# Silverlight / WPF DataTemlate with different data bindings

Tags: silverlight, binding, datatemplate

Normally it would be:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBox Text ="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This means for each item of a list one `TextBox` is bound to a respective property of the bound item.

Is it possible to create a `DataTemplate` with different data bindings for each item?

E.g.: I have a list of product entities. For the first item need the name has to be bound, for the second item it should be the address, for the third the price and so on.

The `TextBox` of the template remains for all items but the `Binding` changes:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBox Text ="{Binding <RunTimePropertyName>}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

note: <""> - changes in `Binding`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a wrapper class around the objects you are binding to.  Something like:

```
public class ItemWrapper : OriginalItem
{
    public int RowNum { get; set; }
    public string TextForRow
    {
        get
        {
            if(RowNum == 0)
                return this.Name
            else if(RowNumb == 1)
                return this.Address
        }
}
```

Then bind to the TextForRow property.

You'll somehow have to fill the RowNum, but I'm assuming that's somewhere in your `OriginalItem`